# Public certificate and Private DNS

Tags: dns, certificate, ssl-certificate

Essentially, I have private domain called `abc.local` and an internal site that I want to be using HTTPS.

I have no Private PKI and planning to create an SSL certificate using Public CA. Let's say I already have a public domain called `zxc.com` and will request for an SSL certificate for `software.zxc.com`.

Can I use this public certificate on the internal site so that the machines in my private domain `abc.local` trust this certificate?

I was thinking on creating a DNS record for it on my private domain but I am doubting it cause it might not work. The DNS record will appear as `software.zxc.com.abc.local` right? So even if I have the public certificate for `software.zxc.com`, it won't appear as trusted is what I believe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate's Common Name (CN) or Subject Alternative Name(s) must match the name in the address bar.

The Web browser will display a certificate warning if the server at https://abc.local/ provides a certificate for software.zxc.com

However, you can point software.zxc.com to the local server's IP (like 192.168.1.x) and https://software.zxc.com/ will work with the green padlock.

Comment: Does it mean when I create a DNS record on my domain at `abc.local` for `software.zxc.com`, it will trust the certificate? Even if its FQDN will essentially be `software.zxc.com.abc.local`? Of course the IP will be the private IP for the server that will host the internal site..

Comment: @ykalyxav: That might actually work, but I think the idea here was to create the DNS record _directly_ at `software.xzc.com` instead of under your internal domain. Public DNS records are not forbidden from pointing at private IP addresses, in general.

Comment: @user1686: A yes the Public DNS. Not really the best practice and I don't really see it being a "security risk". I was just wondering if what I mentioned would work and if anyone have tried it already before a request for public certificate since it induces cost..

Comment: No, how the name is resolved is not related. The certificate must be issued for the name appearing in the URL. If you get a certificate for software.zxc.com, then the URL must be https://software.zxc.com. So you must point software.zxc.com to the IP address that can be used to reach the server. It can be a local or public IP address, it does not matter from the point of view of the browser. Some DNS relays/resolvers may block private IP to protect their users from DNS rebind attacks, you may have to disable this blocking or setup your own local DNS.

Comment: @Dylan: Ah ok. So in a private network with a DNS server, having an `A record` of `software.zxc.com` should also work since putting the short name in the URL will reach the actual server even if its FQDN is `software.zxc.com.abc.local`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: If you run a local DNS that resolves software.zxc.com with the IP adddress of your local server, then you will be able to reach https://software.zxc.com/ and because your server has a certificate for software.zxc.com, it will works.